# What is the Log level to see apex debug statements?

Tags: apex, debug

What is the Log level that should be set to see user-generated debug statements?

Comment: By user-generated debug statements, you were referring to System.debug() calls in Apex methods, correct?

Comment: yes, I was confuse between WARN and Debug . But i thing WARN can not be used for user generated debug statements

Comment: True. Warn does not display `USER_DEBUG` statements. Basically all you will get there are workflows, validation rules, and triggers (but not other classes that they call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see user debug statements with log level "Debug" or higher:

> Debug, Fine, Finer, Finest, Internal.

You don't see user debug statements in levels "Info" or lower:

> Info, Warn, Error

Comment: to avoid lots of noise in the debug logs; do what @sfdcfox suggests -- `System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'mymsg');` or use `LoggingLevel.WARN` or `LoggingLevel.ERROR` and then set your log filters in DC to Apex Code = INFO (or WARN or ERROR) and System = Error.  You'll have shorter logs that are way easier to read

Comment: This answer is not correct. You can see USER_DEBUG messages at any level above NONE, as long as the System.debug statement is specified as equal to or higher than the current logging level.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, I was referring to only the user debug statements generated from the single parameter version of system.debug()

Answer (score 8):

The minimum value to see any debug logs is a System level of ERROR, but most people only use the default logging level, so the usual recommendation is DEBUG. To debug at a lower level than debug, use the two parameter version of System.debug:

```
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, somemessage);
```

Also note, logs over 20mb may be truncated, including your debug messages.